# Postfix alias returns "No such file or directory" for script with #!/usr/bin/env ruby shebang

Tags: postfix-mta, redmine

The postfix alias looks like this:

```
%omitted%: "|/var/www/rails/redmine/extra/mail_handler/rdm-mailhandler.rb --url %omitted% --key %omitted%"
```

The bounce message returned says

"Command died with status 127"

and

"Command output: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory"

I ran

```
sudo -u postfix /usr/bin/env ruby -v
```

and it returned

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2009.10
```

So I assume the postfix user has ruby in its path.

I changed the shebang to /usr/local/bin/ruby and it works but I would prefer to have the code match the svn for the project I checked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix manual [local(8)](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) says about pipe aliases:

> The PATH environment variable is
>   always reset to a system-dependent
>   default path

It seems that /usr/local/bin/ is only in PATH when running interactive shell. You could tweak the PATH environment variable in your OS, but I think it's better to just change the alias to something like:

```
%omitted%: "|/usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/rails/redmine/...
```

Comment: That worked.  I had to run the newaliases command to rebuild the alias database.  Thanks Tonttu

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the command via `sudo` you still have your own environment, therefore your own path. Postfix's `local` program resets the PATH to a minimum (probably /bin and /usr/bin) when invoking an external program. You can use `export_environment` config parameter to set a different path. [More information](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#export_environment)

Answer (score 1):

> So I assume the postfix user has ruby in its path.

No, it means that the user you issued the sudo with has ruby in its path. A simple sudo doesn't change the $PATH.

The simplest solution for your issue probably would be to just prepend the actual ruby to your script call, something like the following (assuming your ruby lives in `/usr/bin/ruby`).

```
%omitted%: "|/usr/bin/ruby /var/www/rails/redmine/extra/mail_handler/rdm-mailhandler.rb --url %omitted% --key %omitted%"
```